# Facebook share dialog open graph debugger

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sharer

I have setup the open graph objects accordingly to how it supposed to be, the open graph debugger finds all the correct information and reports no issues.

The preview 'When shared, this is what will be included' is displaying the correct image, description and link correctly but although when actually sharing the link the image and description is missing (even when trying it in "See this in the share dialog.." in the debugger page).

I have copied all the code from a site where the sharer works perfectly and rewritten the information but it still doesn't work and since the debugger finds all the info I just don't know what to do or where to start.

Anyone who has had the same issue and have any suggestions?

Could it be the special characters, Å, Ä and Ö in the description that is messing this up?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the Share Dialog takes into account special characters. Have you followed the documentation as descibed here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog#jssdk. Have you tried it on a simple html page to make sure it's not just an issue in the debugger?

Comment: @The1Fitz - The share dialog is working fine using the site, the issue is that when I write www.URL.com in my status to be published at my newsfeed the description and image is missing. Which is correctly displayed in the preview.